# git merge against an arbitrary base revision (git-svn)

Tags: git, version-control, merge, git-svn, git-merge

I'm using git-svn for offline development against my company's Subversion repository, which is the project's repository of record. To enable management visibility I'm required to maintain my feature branches in SVN. Sometimes I need to merge changes from our trunk to a feature branch multiple times over the lifetime of the branch. Since I'm required to keep the branch up-to-date in SVN I have to merge; I can't rebase commits once they're pushed to SVN. Further, `git svn dcommit` removes the second parent from merge commits. That means on merges after the first `git merge` identifies the branch root as the merge base instead of the most recent merge parent. It therefore tries to re-merge changes that have already been merged, which pretty much guarantees nasty conflicts.

When I merge in SVN I manually specify the base revision:

```
svn merge -r 49262:49608 $svn/trunk
```

Is there a way in git to do a merge with a manually specified base revision like that?

#### Update:

Note that I need to specify two revisions, both the base and the parent revision. I have a history like

```
trunk: A -- B -- C -- D -- H -- I
             \         \
    feature:  E -- F -- G -- J -- K
```

but `git svn dcommit` has removed the parent relationship between `G` and `D`. I need to run a merge of `I` on to `K` with a base of `D`. Simply running

```
$ git checkout feature
$ git merge trunk
```

will try to merge `I` on to `K` with a base of `B` instead of `D`, which re-applies `C` and `D` resulting in extreme merge conflicts. With SVN I would run a command like

```
$ svn switch $svn/feature
$ svn merge -r D:I $svn/trunk
```

but `git merge` does not have an option to specify the base revision `D`. I'm looking for something like

```
$ git merge --base D trunk
```

but such an option doesn't appear to exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(edit: for a lower-level way of doing this see previous revisions, this way's fastest though)

- make a nonce commit with `feature`'s tree parented on the correct merge base

  ```
  git checkout `git commit-tree -p $D -m - feature^{tree}`
  ```
- merge trunk into that as usual

  ```
  git merge trunk --no-commit
  git commit    # the two-stepper gets the commit message someplace known
  ```
- commit the merged tree as the new `feature` tip

  ```
  git commit-tree -p feature -p trunk -F .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG HEAD^{tree} \
          | xargs git checkout -B feature
  ```

---

Comment: This works well with the caveat that the merge command is `git-merge-one-file`, not `merge-one-file`, at least in my installation of git on OS X.

Comment: Also note that this is much slower than running `git merge` because it fork+exec's a new process for each conflicted file. If `git merge` is choosing the wrong base version I don't see much other choice, though.

Comment: @SamHanes ow. thanks for sticking with that, sorry for the braino. Fixed.

Comment: You can also use `git update-ref MERGE_HEAD trunk` to record the merge parent instead of calling `git merge`. That has the benefit of working if you do it after calling `git read-tree -m`.

Comment: @SamHanes Thank you!  You've been as much help to me as me to you on this.

Comment: @SamHanes and I think what's there now is what should have been there all along.  This certainly helped me, thanks again.

Comment: I can verify that the new version as of 2013-11-12 also works and is indeed comparable in performance to a normal `git merge` (because it is one). It will warn you that you're abandoning two commits, which is intended and fine.

Comment: This question and answer makes me want to run back to `cvs up -j revA -j revB`.

Answer (score 0):

You might try `git merge <commit hashcode>` where the hashcode of the commit can be found using `git log`

**Update:**

Based on your revision, I *think* what you're looking for is the following.  Start by doing `git branch D`.  You should be able to get the commit hash for D by doing `git status`.  Then, do `git checkout feature`.  Then do `git merge newBranchFromD`.  This will put the state of feature into a merged state, from D, from the trunk.

You could also, in order to keep a cleaner commit history, do a `git rebase newBranchFromD` after checking out the feature branch.  Be warned, this inserts H into the correct place in the commit history, so that you'd end up with:

```
           trunkAtD:    -- H -- I
                       /
trunk: A -- B -- C -- D -- H -- I
    \         \
    feature:  E -- F -- G -- H -- I -- J -- K
```

This is a little different than a merge commit, as rebase puts all commits in chronological order in your commit history.  Another option you have is to use --squash on your commit, so that the merge doesn't attempt to auto-commit.

Use rebase with caution, as it can cause unexpected outcomes if it's not being used when you know what's going on with it.

Comment: `git merge <commit>` specifies the parent rev. I need to also specify the base rev, something like `git merge --base current-branch-base remotes/trunk`.

Comment: Maybe branch at the base commit, check out that branch, then merge with the other branch?

Comment: I've updated the question with a better explanation of the existing history and what I'm trying to do. Can you explain your suggestion in terms of that history?

Comment: Sure, I'll update my answer to better reflect what I think you're going for (I hope)

Answer (score 0):

This is what we did. We first found the hash of the merge commit that had lost its 'merge' - MISSING_MERGE, Second we found the commit which that commit had merged in - MERGED_POINT.

Then we went to the receiving branch and created a fake commit

```
git merge -s ours MERGED_POINT --no-commit
git commit -m "Fake commit because MISSING_MERGE is not marked as a merge commit"
```

We can then see

```
git merge-base OURS THEIRS
```

that we now have the correct base again.