# Merge disjoint branches with git

Tags: git, version-control, merge

#### My current situation

I have 2 git repositories of the same software project, where one is the fork of the other:

```
fork:                A1 - B1 - C1 - ... - HEAD_FORK
                      :
       (Some changes done outside of git)
                      :
orig: A2 - B2 - C2 - D2 - E2 - ... - HEAD_ORIGINAL
```

These two histories are completely disjoint, they share no common commit. (as far as git is concerned)

However based on the timestamps and the fact that I know that *fork* was forked from *orig* (not using a VCS, but the usual dirty "just copy the files and create a new repository" way) I can find a point of "minimal difference" between the two:

A1 is based on D2 minus some files.

#### My goal

Merge this mess. I want *fork* with all the useful changes from *orig* after the fork.

I don't care about the history of *orig*. One large commit on *fork* would be fine. (I could split and refactor that anyway)

#### My current battle plan

I already have a git repository which contains both histories as branches. What I plan to do:

1. Create a branch *orig-old* where D2 is HEAD and a branch *fork-old* where A1 is HEAD.

   ```
   fork-old:                  A1 <- HEAD_FORK-OLD
                               :
                               :
   orig-old:   A2 - B2 - C2 - D2 <- HEAD_ORIG-OLD
   ```
2. Merge *fork-old* and *orig-old* creating *common-old*

   ```
   fork-old:                  A1 <- HEAD_FORK-OLD
                               : \
   common-old:                 :  A3 <- HEAD_COMMON-OLD
                               : /
   orig-old:   A2 - B2 - C2 - D2 <- HEAD_ORIG-OLD
   ```
3. Rebase *fork* on *common-old*

   ```
   fork:                         B1 - C1 - D1 - .... - HEAD_FORK
                                 /
   common-old:                  A3 <- HEAD_COMMON-OLD
                                /
   orig-old:    A2 - B2 - C2 - D2 <- HEAD_ORIG-OLD
   ```
4. Rebase *orig* on *fork*

   ```
   orig:                                E2 - F2 - ... - HEAD_ORIG
                                        /
   fork:         B1 - C1 - D1 - .... - X1 <- HEAD_FORK
                 /
   common-old:  A3 <- HEAD_COMMON-OLD
   ```
5. Merge the rebased *orig* using merge --squash onto *fork*.

   ```
   orig:                         E2 - F2 - ... - K2 <- HEAD_ORIG
                                 /                \
   fork:  B1 - C1 - D1 - .... - X1 -------------- M1 <- HEAD_FORK
   ```
6. Create a diff between the new HEAD of *fork* M1 and the old head (the HEAD of the forked repository) and apply it to the forked repository.

#### My question

Did anyone here try to do something similar and has some experience if that will work?
Since we are taking about quite a large undertaking here (multiple days at least), it would be nice to know if my plan is insanity before I start to merge all this.

I also considered just copying everything from *orig* and paste it over the files in *fork*
and then selectively add changes with "git add --patch" but I think for that there are just to much complex changes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [git merge against an arbitrary base revision (git-svn)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19871000/git-merge-against-an-arbitrary-base-revision-git-svn)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like git-graft may help. Basically it allows you to manually stitch history.

Here are couple of articles describing details procedure:
http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2010/03/stitching-git-histories.html
http://ben.straubnet.net/post/939181602/git-grafting-repositories

If you add a graft to make A1 a descendant of D2, git merge may do a passable job merging in the rest of the changes. If there's substantial difference between A1  and D2, you may first do `git merge -s ours A1` to tell git that those differences should be considered merged so they would not get in the way when you do `git merge HEAD_FORK`

Actually, with `git merge -s ours A1` you may not need any grafts at all as that fake merge will join the histories of two branches, though not at the exact point in history. Should not make much of a difference considering that there were no other merges across branches.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to stitch together the two branches using `git merge -s ours A1` first. That will probably save me all that  juggling with so much branches. Also, I didn't know about git-grafts before, so that will be the next option.

Comment: `git merge -s ours A1` worked beautifully. The merge conflicts where what would be expected but nothing to bad. Thanks!